# Action.Submit values are not captured in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, botframework

I have a node.js bot project in which i'm trying to call an api .if api doesn't find given questions answer it will ask for adaptive card form to fill up by user else it will show correct response. **But when submit button is clicked in card it captures data but undefined value is passed in node.js code**.

Work around:

```
calling API with user query, and storing result
if(response not found)
{
//calling adaptive card form for user inputs
}
else{
//display output
}
```

My json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Please enter your details"
      },
      {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "firstName",
        "placeholder": "What is your first name?"
      },
      {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "lastName",
        "placeholder": "What is your last name?"
      },
      {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "email",
        "placeholder": "What is your Email?"
      }
   
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit",
        "data": {
          "x": 13,  
          "firstName": "${firstName.value}",
          "lastName": "${lastName.value}",
          "email": "${email.value}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

my node.js code

```
const {CardFactory} = require('botbuilder'); 
const TicketCreationCard = require('./adaptiveCards/ticketCreation');
const CARDS = [
    TicketCreationCard
    ];
const { ActivityHandler, MessageFactory } = require('botbuilder');


class EchoBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {

           

            const ques = context.activity.text
            const query = '?user_input='+ques
            console.log(query);
            const completequery = url+query;
            console.log(completequery);
            let response = ""
            let responseNotFound ="I do not know."
            

            const { default: fetch } = await import('node-fetch');
            
            await fetch(completequery, {
                method: 'GET', // specify the HTTP method
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json' // set the Content-Type header
                }
              })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                response = data['result']
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
            
           console.log(response.replace("/\\n/gm","  "))
           
           //If answer not found
           if (response.includes(responseNotFound))
           {
            
            await context.sendActivity ({
                attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(CARDS[0])]
                });
            var txt = context.activity.text;
            console.log("txt",txt)
            var val = context.activity.value;
            console.log("val",val)
            // Check if the activity came from a submit action
            if(val != undefined){
                //var user = context.activity.value;
                await context.sendActivity("hello , your firstName : " + val.firstName + ",lastName :" + val.lastName);

            }
            
           }
          else{
            const replyText = `Assistant: ${response}`;
            // const replyText = ques;

            await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text(replyText, replyText));

           } 
            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
```

On Bot emulator
[image: adaptive card]

On submit button it captures values
[image: On Submit button click]

But in code it shows undefined
[image: Node.js not capturing values]

As I'm new to this any help will be thankful.

Comment: It's possible I've just missed it, but I do not see where in your code you are storing the submission from the adaptive card. Have you ensured that, for example, there is a property called `value` containing the response? I would suggest running the bot with breakpoints and stepping through with the debugger to find out what variables are set and when.